# UITextField on text change not counting letters properly when adding/deleting

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have the following code for my `UITextField`.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.removeAll()
    if let text = textField.text {
        for i in 0..<cardBoxItemsArray.count {
            var searchedFor = cardBoxItemsArray[i].searchedFor
            if (searchedFor.contains("\(text.uppercased())")) {
                cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.append(cardBoxItemsArray[i])
            }
        }
        
        print("TEXT COUNT: \(text.count)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    return true
}
```

When I type in my first letter/number, the `"TEXT COUNT"` says 0. I expect this to be 1.

When I erase everything, the `"TEXT COUNT"` says 1. I expect this to be 0.

The strings I am comparing, as another example, I have 3 as 2018 and 1 as 2019. If I type in 2019 into my `UITextField`, The filtered array shows 2018 AND 2019 strings.

This is causing the filtered array to not be deleted fully at still show in my UITableView

Here are the TableView functions.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.count > 0) {
        return self.cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.count
    }
    return self.cardBoxItemsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? MyCardBoxCell {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        if (cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.count > 0) {
            let responseItems = cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered[indexPath.row]
            print(responseItems.searchedFor)
            cell.configureCell(currentItem: responseItems)
        } else {
            let responseItems = cardBoxItemsArray[indexPath.row]
            print(responseItems.searchedFor)
            cell.configureCell(currentItem: responseItems)
        }
        
        //cell.mDelegate = self
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell
    } else {
        return MyCardBoxCell()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me. I am counting it using `replacingCharacters`

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.removeAll()
    let nsString = NSString(string: filterCardBox.text!.uppercased())
    let stringCount = nsString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if (stringCount.count > 0) {
        for i in 0..<cardBoxItemsArray.count {
            var searchedFor = cardBoxItemsArray[i].searchedFor
            if (searchedFor.contains("\(nsString)")) {
                cardBoxItemsArrayFiltered.append(cardBoxItemsArray[i])
            }
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    
    return true
}
```